# Show that $x^{\overline {n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{n!}{k!}x^{\underline{k}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to proof the following:

$\displaystyle x^{\overline {n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{n!}{k!}x^{\underline{k}}$

where

$x^{\overline {n}}=x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n-1)$ (rising factorial)

and

$x^{\underline{k}}=x(x-1)...(x-k+1)$ (falling factorial)

With the hint:
Consider $a_kx^{\underline{k}}$. Define $D(p(x)):=p(x+1)-p(x)$, using $D$ one can calculate a formula for $a_k$
Find the formula for $a_k$ and use this formula to show the above equality.

My attempt:
I first tried to calculate $a_k$
$a_kx^{\underline{k}}=a_k x (x-1)(x-2)...(x-k+1)$

Applying $D$

$D (a_k x (x-1)...(x-k+1))=a_k ((x+1) x (x-1)...(x-k+2)-x(x-1)...(x-k+1))=a_k k x^{\underline{k-1}}$

Thus, $D^k (a_k x (x-1)...(x-k+1))=a_k k! x^{\underline{k-k}}=a_k k!$

By this I get the formula $a_k=D^k x^{\underline{k}} \dfrac{1}{k!}$

I did calculate that $Dx^{\overline{n}}=(1-n)x^{\overline{n+1}}$

Now

$x^{\overline{n}}=c_0 +c_1 x^{\underline{1}}+...+c_n x^{\underline{n}}$

If I apply $D^n$
I get

$x^{\overline{n+n}}=n! c_n x^{\underline{n-n}}$

$x(x+1)...(x+2n-1)=n! c_n$

I don't really know how to continue from here on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\fall}[1]{^{\underline{#1}}}$
The fact that $D[x\fall k]=kx\fall{k-1}$ implies the following. (I think you were already aware of this Lemma, because you wrote $a_k=\frac1{k!}D^kx\fall k$, but it does not hurt to be extra clear).

> **Lemma:** If  $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x\fall k$, then for each $m\in \{0,\dots,n\}$, $a_m$ is equal to $\frac1{m!}D^m[p(x)]$ evaluated at $x=0$.
>
> *Proof:* Note that $\frac1{m!} D^m[p(x)]=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\cdot \frac{k(k-1)\cdots (k-m+1)}{m!} x\fall {k-m}$. The terms with indices $k=0$ through $m-1$ are all zero because of the $k(k-1)\cdots (k-m+1) $ factor. The terms with $k > m$ all have a factor of $x$. Therefore, when you evaluated at $x=0$, only the $k=m$ term remains, and it is exactly equal to $a_m$. $\hspace{.1cm}\square$

We know that $\{x\fall 0,x\fall 1,\dots, x\fall {n}\}$ is a basis for the vector space of polynomials with degree at most $n$. This implies that we can write
$$
x^{\overline{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x\fall k,
$$
for some coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_{n}$. We then apply the Lemma to find what the $a_k$ are:
\begin{align}
a_k
  &=\frac1{k!}D^k [x^{\overline n}]\;\Big|_{x=0}
\\&=\frac1{k!}D^k [(x+n-1)\fall {n}]\;\Big|_{x=0}
\\&=\frac1{k!}(n)(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1) (x+n-1)\fall {n-k}\;\Big|_{x=0}
\\&=\frac1{k!}\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\cdot (n-1)\fall{n-k}
\\&=\frac{n!}{k!} \cdot \frac1{(n-k)!} \cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}
\\&=\frac{n!}{k!} \cdot \binom{n-1}{k-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by $n!$ we obtain

$$\frac{x^{\overline{n}}}{n!}
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n-1\choose k-1} \frac{x^{\underline{k}}}{k!}.$$

This is

$${x+n-1\choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n-1\choose k-1} {x\choose k}.$$

The sum is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n-1\choose n-k} {x\choose k}
= [z^n] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} z^k {x\choose k}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor.
Continuing,

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n-1} (1+z)^x = [z^n] (1+z)^{x+n-1}
= {x+n-1\choose n}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: where do you get $z$?

Comment: I dont really understand the step from $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-1}{n-k} \binom{x}{k}=[z^n] (1+z)^{n-1} \sum_{k \geq}z^k \binom{x}{k}$. Could you explain what you do here?

Comment: This is a [coefficient extractor for formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).

Comment: Thank you very much